# Change resolved path from vue config

Tags: linux, vue.js, npm

I want to change the path of `.vuerc` file. I have vue installed via npm.
When I run `vue config` the resolved path is `/home/username/.vuerc` and I want that to be something like `/home/username/.config/vue/vuerc`, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't modify the path to this file, there's no options for this.

But you can try to set a symbolic link?

```
cd ~
# Move the file to the desired folder
mv ~/.vuerc ~/config/vue/vuerc

# Create a symlink to the real file with the original file name
ln -s ~/config/vue/vuerc .vuerc
```

Comment: This can be a solution, but I don't want to have the file or the symbolic link.